# How can i best protect the IV and key password in this javax.crypto Server Client

Tags: java, android, encryption

I have for a few days reading this and other tutorials about javax.crypto
[Using block modes and initialisation vectors in Java](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/block_modes_java.shtml)

My test code below is a Client who send data to a Server.

I read about different block modes and the CFB8 stream mode seem to be working because i split arbitrary size files up in chunks. Every chunk is 0.5MB except for the last chunk that are smaller, they are sent one after another to the Server that put the file back together.

I have a few questions:

1) Should i use Asymmetric cryptography publ/priv keys to send the SecretKeySpec password and the IV to the server before i start the transfer?

2) What are the SecretKeySpec password used for, protect the IV?

**THE CLIENT encrypt data**

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB8/NoPadding"); 
SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec("password12345678".getBytes(), "AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);

AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();

out.write(iv); //Send IV to Server
out.flush();

// THE ENCRYPTET STREAM
cos = new CipherOutputStream(out, cipher);  

while ((val = byteArrayInputStream.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0) {
       cos.write(buffer, 0, val);
       cos.flush();
}

cipher.doFinal()
```

**THE SERVER decrypt data**

```
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    in.read(iv);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB8/NoPadding"); 
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec("password12345678".getBytes(), "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

    cos = new CipherInputStream(in, cipher);        

   while (offset < tmpBuffer.length && (numRead=cos.read(tmpBuffer, offset,      tmpBuffer.length-offset)) >= 0) {
      offset += numRead;
      savedFileSize = savedFileSize + numRead;
   }    
   // CREATE HASH FROM THE DOWNLOAD CHUNK PART
   String retCrC = DoEncryption.getCRC32ChecksumFromArray(tmpBuffer);
   String hash2 = Long.toHexString( Long.parseLong(retCrC) );

   // TEST SO THE REMOTE HASH MATCH THE LOCAL HASH
   if(!hash1.equals(hash2)){
   ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I use asymmetric cryptography publ/priv keys to send the SecretKeySpec password and the IV to the server before I start the transfer?

This is broadly how SSL works, albeit usually in reverse.  Any reason you couldn't use SSL/TLS instead?  Generating your own secure transfer protocol is not a trivial undertaking.

Comment: Yea your right SSL come to think of it. This code is in production now in an Android app called SPRiiD. I wanted to try this CipherOutputStream first to get to know a little how stuff works and then dive into SSL

Comment: @Erik you should read Beginning Cryptography with Java.  It's ace.

Comment: thanks love it but not enough time go that deep. If i switch to SSL now can you recommend some tutorial for Android SSL. Not talking about self-signed certificate. I Realize the topic is massive and maybe SSL with a CA is easier

Comment: If you're using a CA, then you can probably use http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html just like you'd use a regular socket.

Comment: Love the book and all examples Chapter:2 Symmetric what i just learned, Chap3 very nice hackattack scenario and hashing. Just need some plastic tape and earplugs now.

Comment: You don't happen to have a working example source code for the book. I'm copy paste from the book because the source code wont build. The bouncycastle imports are so much deprecated. I will do without just didn't want to miss anything.

Comment: I can only recommend http://www.bouncycastle.org/documentation.html.  If you read that, it'll direct you towards the source, which has a number of examples.

Answer (score 1):

Usually one protects the IV by including it into the HMAC.

Comment: Yes the Hmac was my thought to. What about my Question nr:2?

Answer (score 0):

To protect my simple code in the question one can use SSL/TSL.

Got everything working using SSL/TSL with self-signed certificates from the blog here:
[@Marcus Krantz's blog Creating iself-signed certificates](http://blog.callistaenterprise.se/2011/11/24/creating-self-signed-certificates-for-use-on-android/)

I must say this is not for the faint hearted..:)

BTW Is it true that only the bcprov-jdk15on-146 works and not the bcprov-jdk15on-147 when using the keytool for the *.bks files?